# Increase Plot Size in Python with subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to resize the plots from this code but i don't know how to. 
this code results plots but so tiny..

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 1) 

plt.plot(raw_turen['ABJ'], color='blue')
plt.title('ABJ Turen')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 2)
plt.plot(raw_gondanglegi['ABJ'], color='green')
plt.title('ABJ Gondanglegi')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 3)
plt.plot(raw_donomulyo['ABJ'], color='black')
plt.title('ABJ Donomulyo')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 4)
plt.plot(raw_kepanjen['ABJ'], color='red')
plt.title('ABJ Kepanjen')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 5)
plt.plot(raw_bululawang['ABJ'], color='magenta')
plt.title('ABJ Bululawang')

# Improve spacing between subplots and display them
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

this is the result :

[image: result]

Comment: add `plt.figure(figsize=(size_y, size_x))` before your type the first `plt.subplot`

Answer (score 0):

If you're plotting it initially then include `figsize=(x,y)` as an argument in `plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))`, where `x` and `y` are lengths with appropriate units.

If you've already created the figure, but not plotted it, and are referencing the figure with, say `figure1`, then use `plt.figure(num=figure1, figsize=(x,y))`.  You can also include other arguments here as well.